# Бинарное возведение в степень длинных чисел

Tags: c++

Суть вопроса в том, как поступить при очень больших числах, в массив запихать и оттуда брать или как?

Сам алгоритм бинарного возведения:

```
int bistep(unsigned  int a,unsigned  int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 1)
        return binpow (a, n-1) * a;
    else {
        int b = binpow (a, n/2);
        return b * b;
    }
}
```

спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Готовые решения/библиотеки не возбраняются?

Comment: @Саня  А что означает "бинарное возведение в степень"?

Answer (score 1):

Уже писал один раз, повторюсь...

Значит, так. Чтоб закрыть тему - бегом набросал умножение, сложение и возведение в степень. Только - набросано за полчаса, вроде работает, но кое-где веревочками перевязано :) - типа нормализации после умножения вместо корректного расписывания переносов.

Об оптимальности говорить не приходится :( Тем не менее вроде работает.

Только консультаций по тому, что делает та или иная строчка кода, простите, но - не будет. Разбирайтесь сами. Числа храню для простоты в виде кусков по 9 цифр.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class superLong
{
public:
    using ullong = unsigned long long;
    superLong(ullong x = 0) { d.push_back(x); };
    superLong(string s);
    operator string() const;

    friend superLong operator *(const superLong&a, const superLong&b);
    friend superLong operator +(const superLong&a, const superLong&b);

private:
    vector<ullong> d;
    static constexpr ullong max = 1000000000ull;
};


superLong operator *(const superLong&a, const superLong&b)
{
    superLong r;
    for(size_t i = 0, e = a.d.size(); i < e; ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0, f = b.d.size(); j < f; ++j)
        {
            superLong::ullong v = a.d[i]*b.d[j];
            superLong::ullong carry = v/superLong::max;
            v = v%superLong::max;
            if (i+j >= r.d.size()) r.d.resize(i+j+1,0);
            r.d[i+j] += v;
            if (carry)
            {
                if (i+j+1 >= r.d.size()) r.d.resize(i+j+2,0);
                r.d[i+j+1] += carry;
            }
        }
    }
    for(size_t i = 0, e = r.d.size(); i < e-1; ++i)
    {
        if (r.d[i] > superLong::max)
        {
            r.d[i+1] += r.d[i] / superLong::max;
            r.d[i] %= superLong::max;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

superLong operator +(const superLong&a, const superLong&b)
{
    superLong d((a.d.size() > b.d.size()) ? a : b);
    superLong c((a.d.size() > b.d.size()) ? b : a);
    c.d.resize(d.d.size(),0);
    superLong::ullong carry = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < d.d.size(); ++i)
    {
        d.d[i] += c.d[i]+carry;
        carry = d.d[i]/superLong::max;
        d.d[i] %= superLong::max;
    }
    if (carry) d.d.push_back(carry);
    return d;
}

superLong::superLong(string s)
{
    superLong q;
    int len = s.length()%9;
    if (len)
    {
        string val = s.substr(0,len);
        s = s.substr(len,s.length()-len);
        q = stoll(val);
    }
    while (s.length())
    {
        string val = s.substr(0,9);
        s = s.substr(9,s.length()-9);
        q = q * superLong::max + stoll(val);
    }
    d = std::move(q.d);
}

superLong::operator string() const
{
    string s;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {
        char buf[12];
        snprintf(buf,12,"%09lld",d[i]);
        s = buf + s;
    }
    return s;
}

superLong superPow(superLong x, unsigned long long p)
{
    superLong r(1);
    while(p)
    {
        if (p&0x01) r = r * x;
        p >>= 1;
        x = x*x;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    superLong l1("111111111111111111111253672373");
    superLong l2("552345678012345678012898234897");
    cout << string(l1*l2) << endl<<endl;;
    cout << string(superPow(2,1000)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ниче так, плюсую!)))

Answer (score 0):

> в массив запихать и от туда брать или как?
>
> спасибо за любую помощь!

Самый главный совет - почитайте старенькую и очень надежную))) книжку `"Системы счисления",С.В.Фомин,5-е издание,1987г.` ([вот вам залил](https://yadi.sk/i/SyZ1rM1j33YG6Y)).

Самый главный вопрос - "как представлять очень большие числа?". В нашем случае очевидных вариантов представлений три:

- десятичное представление (1 байт на 10-чную цифру, используем, например, `std::vector<uint8_t>`)
- двоично-десятичное представление (на 10-чную цифру выделяем 4 бита, используем например `std::vector<uint8_t>` для пар цифр, или `std::bitset<разрядность>`
- двоичное представление (не используем для представления 10-чную систему счисления, работаем строго с двоичной, без вариантов `std::bitset<разрядность>`)

Перечисленные выше представления требуют свою "арифметику". Выбор за вами, ибо всегда есть плюсы и минусы. Сложность реализации может окупиться большей скоростью и/или экономией памяти. И наоборот, простота реализаций может потребовать излишних ресурсов.

**Не в угоду перфекционизму, а справедливости ради...**

Поищите в сети материалы на тему "Прикладная теория цифровых автоматов", и раздел, об "умножении на два разряда одновременно". Хотя там речь пойдет скорее всего об аппаратных реализациях - не пугайтесь, теория хороша. И в программной реализации, надеюсь, не подведет. В случае циклических умножений (а в вашем случае это именно так), данный подход возможно позволит значительно ускорить операции. Речь идет о замене бОльшого числа аппаратных умножений, на мЕньшее количество табличных выборок и сдвигов со сложением.

Нет преграды патриотам (С) ДМБ :-)